# Looking for Date parser library with Locale and Timezone support in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, titanium

I know that there are many Javascript libraries that parse and format dates in Javascript, but I would like to use one that allows parse date strings as this:

```
"sáb, 5 ene 2013 13:21:24 PST"
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
"Sat, 5 jan 2013 21:21:24 UTC"
```

I like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and [sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/), both of them are good libraries and have support for different locales, but, AFAIK, they don't support timezone in the form: "CES, PST, CET, ...", only the iso format "+01:00".

I've tested many others libraries and the only that fits the requirements is [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) that works fine, but there are 2 things that I don't like about it, the project seems to be abandoned since 2007 and It doesn't support module load with require() because was created for web use and I need it for Titanium Mobile app, so libraries compliant with Node.js fit better.

In other words, I need a Javascript lib that allows me to do this (with their own API methods):

```
var DateHelper = require('my-date-helper-lib');
var strDate = 'sáb, 5 ene 2013 13:21:24 PST';
console.log(strDate + ' => ' + DateHelper.parse(strDate).toISOFormat());
```

That code should prints in console something like:

```
sáb, 5 ene 2013 13:21:24 PST => 2013-01-05 21:21:24+0000
```

I could modify date.js to use it in my app, but If there is any other library that doesn't need to be touched I prefer it.

Does anyone know any library that fits such requirements ?

Comment: Not an answer you will like, but you could fork for example sugar.js on github and make it work: https://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar/blob/master/lib/date.js

Comment: A Do-It-Yourself is always an option :-), but my question is about a lib that already does the job, besides, date.js lib works but has some caveats and as I said in my question I would like to know if there is a better option.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the module [timezone](https://npmjs.org/package/timezone):

```
var tz = require('timezone/loaded'),
    equal = require('assert').equal,
    utc;

// Get POSIX time in UTC.
utc = tz('2012-01-01');

// Convert UTC time to local time in a localize language.
equal(tz(utc, '%c', 'fr_FR', 'America/Montreal'),
      'sam. 31 déc. 2011 19:00:00 EST');
```

Comment: Hi @werner-vesteras your answer is interesting but I didn't find a way to parse string dates with this module, It uses the default built-in Date object to parse strings, however is very full-featured for format dates, but that is not my need. Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see a way to parse the example string that I put in my question, please let me know if I'm wrong.